# Java getter and setter issue

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

When setting a value in `setData` the value is OK in String `returnDataTab1`, but when `getId()` states it's null. Is the issue staring me in the face.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;    
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;


    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        Context context;
        String dataResponse = "";
        String returnDataTab1;


        //getter
        public String getId()
        {
//The system out below shows a value of null although the setData method set it ok.

            System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz : "+returnDataTab1);
            return returnDataTab1;

        }

        public void setData(String newResult)
        {
            returnDataTab1=newResult;

            System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz : "+returnDataTab1);

/// the returnDataTab value is set ok

        }






        BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String urlLogin  = "";


            String task = params[0];
            String loginusername="";
            String loginpassword="";




            if (task.equals("login"))
            {          
              urlLogin  = "http://domain/LoginAndRegister-login.php";
              loginusername = params[1];
              loginpassword = params[2];
             //


                try 
                {
                    URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);


                    //send the driver number to the database
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                    String myDatalogin = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginEmail","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginusername,"UTF-8")
                    +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginPassword","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginpassword,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.write(myDatalogin);
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    //get response from the database
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    //String dataResponse = "";
                    String inputLine = "";

                     while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                     {
                        dataResponse += inputLine;
                     }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    return  dataResponse;
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }//end if statement






        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


        /// gets value OK from background task
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)

        {
            this.setData(result);       

        }

}
```

Would appreciate if you guys could take a look and point out the obvious mistake.

This is the code called from a tab

```
 BackgroundTask backgroundTaskLogin = new BackgroundTask(Tab1Activity.this);    
               backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task,username,password);

               String x;
               x=backgroundTaskLogin.getId();

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Response : "+x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The values are set from

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)

            {
                this.setData(result);   
// gets result value fine   

            }
```

Comment: When did you call the `getId()`??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We need to know how you used the setters and getter. Post the code where you used the setter and getter

Comment: What @Gigaxel said is true we need to see how are you producing this error. It is clear that whenever you check returnDataTab1there might be something in the setter however this might not be the case when you retrieve the data. Remember you are using an AsyncTask and this implies you are forking from the main thread. I do not see any point in doing a setter/getter in an AsyncTask. Send all the data the AsyncTask might need in the params, recover whatever you need in onPostExecute or the result of doInBackground.

Comment: When you call `backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task,username,password)`, the thread is forked. I assume you want to go on after the login has been performed: You can pass an object with a callback function to the constructor of your backgroundLoginTask, and call that callback function during `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. What I would like to know is ho come the sting in
public String getId() 

is null